# How can I emulate MbUnit's [MultipleCulture] attribute in MSTest?

Tags: mstest, culture, mbunit

MbUnit has a great attribute: [MultipleCultureAttribute](http://www.gallio.org/api/html/T_MbUnit_Framework_MultipleCultureAttribute.htm).

I am wondering if there is an easy way to do this in MSTest? So far, the best I can come up with is:

- Externalizating the actual test code to a private method
- Saving the current culture
- Setting the culture and calling the private method (repeated for each culture)
- And finally, reverting to the original culture

At best, it can be described as ugly ... and verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach may be to use an anonymous delegate, however keep in mind that MSTest will treat this as a single test so it may be difficult to distinguish results for different cultures.

eg. Rough code for anonymous delegate approach.

```
public static class MultipleCultures
{
    public static void Do(Action action, params CultureInfo[] cultures)
    {
        CultureInfo originalCulture = Thread.CurrentCulture;

        try
        {
            foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
            {
                Thread.CurrentCulture = culture;

                try
                {
                    action();
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed while running test with culture '{0}'.", culture.Name);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            Thread.CurrentCulture = originalCulture;
        }
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class Fixture
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        MultipleCultures.Do(() =>
        {
            // test code...
        }, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CultureInfo.GetCulture("en-GB"));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer. I have marked it so.

But, as you can see from my profile, I am a new user and forgot some important information in the question. My company is a VB.NET shop and we will not get statement lamdas until VS2010.

This is what I allude to in the question because it seems that I would need to put the actual test code into a private method and pass a function pointer to the Do() method. This creates a test disconnect, in my opinion.

Is there anything else short of major work to extend the MSTest framework?

Comment: Unfortunately MSTest does not have an extensibility story for decorations like this.  So your implementation choices are severely limited unless you change frameworks or languages.